# onsen-UIが読み込まれていない？

Tags: javascript, android, onsen-ui, visual-studio

onsen-UI使っています。
Visualstudioを使っています。
UIのスライドメニューというか、ハンバーガー？のアイコンの動きとページ偏移は、正常にできます。

でも、下記のソースのように、clickの動作とセンサーの部分が動きません。

色々ネット検索して試行錯誤していますが、解決できず困っています。
ご教授頂けましたら幸いです。

onclickのイベントは使えます。

`<ons-button modifier="large" (click)="mytest()">開始</ons-button>`

このclickの部分をonclickに書き換えて回避しました。
でも、加速度センサーが動かないので、色々と調べていました。
すると、センサーを使うようにコードを書きましたが、動いていない様子です。

```
var watchID = null;

//cordova 読み込みまで待つ
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

//加速度センサー　更新時間
var options = { frequency: 1000 };  // 1秒ごとに更新

//センサー戻り値
watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);

alert(watchID);

// イベント発生
function onSuccess(acceleration) {

    // x軸
    var x = acceleration.x;
    // y軸
    var y = acceleration.y;
    // z軸
    var z = acceleration.z;

    document.getElementById('xDir').innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById('yDir').innerHTML = y;
    document.getElementById('zDir').innerHTML = z;
```

このソースで、デバッグの為に入れた
`alert(watchID);`
が動かないのです。

センサーのX,y,zの値も、返ってきません。

画像のようにJavaScriptのファイルを配置しています。
[image: Visualstudioのファイル配置]

HTMLのヘッダーは、このように書いています。

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://unpkg.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onsenui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onsen-css-components.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!--
    <script src="js/angular-onsenui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/onsen_tp.js"></script>
```

angularをコメントにしているのは、競合するのか確認するためです。
コメントにする前も、コメントにしてからもonsen-UIのAPIやイベントは、起きていないです。

プラグインは、インストールしています。
[image: Visualstudioのプラグイン画面]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peVdB.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxbec.png

このソースを書き加えてテストしましたが、アラートがうごかないです。

ons.ready(function () {
    // CordovaのAPIを呼び出す準備が整った
    console.log(window.device);
    alert("ok");
});

再度試したところ、ちゃんとOKが返ってきました。
これから、clickのイベントを確かめます。
また、センサーは、動きません。
今、実機デバッグしています。
このアプリは、ウェブアプリで作ったときは、正常に動作しています。
デバッグで使っているスマホでも、センサー使うことが出来ました。。

実機デバッグでも、センサーとclickが反応しません。

ons.readyから返事があったので、センサーを、このイベントが起きたら設定する様に書いてみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。

ons.ready(function () {
    // CordovaのAPIを呼び出す準備が整った

```
//加速度センサー　更新時間
var options = { frequency: 1000 };  // 1秒ごとに更新

//センサー戻り値
watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

});

Cordovaのテンプレートの最後の方に、大事なスクリプト3行を見つけました。
これをコピペして、試しているところです。
ブラウザのエミュレータでは、変化なかったので、実機デバイスでの確認を試みています。

2018/04/11追記
先日Cordovaのテンプレートの下の方に見つけたJavaScriptの3行をコピペしてビルドまでしましたが変化ありませんでした。

2018/04/12自己解決しました。
　　　　
clickのイベントは、onclickしかないようですね。
Monacaにログおインして、テンプレートを見たら、onclickが使われていました。

それからセンサーに関しては、下記のコードを書いたら、できました。

```
    function onDeviceReady(){
        console.log("センサーが使えるようになりました！");
    }
```

(click)は、無いみたいですね、
今日Monacaにログインして、テンプレートを確認したら、onclickが使われていました。

Visualstudioのブラウザのエミュレーションでも、センサーを使うことが出来ました。
[image: ブラウザのエミュレーションのモーションセンサーの値]

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 0):

clickのイベントは、onclickしかないようですね。
Monacaにログおインして、テンプレートを見たら、onclickが使われていました。

それからセンサーに関しては、下記のコードを書いたら、できました。

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    console.log("センサーが使えるようになりました！");
}
```

(click)は、無いみたいですね、
今日Monacaにログインして、テンプレートを確認したら、onclickが使われていました。

Visualstudioのブラウザのエミュレーションでも、センサーを使うことが出来ました。
自己解決しましたので、改めて回答として書きました。
使い方に慣れていないため、申し訳ありません。